# Python - How do I give a value from one script to another?

Tags: python, class, logging

So I am trying to use a sort of two script where I want to exchange values between each other. What I mean by that is that etc. when I want to print out something such as `logger.log("print me")` This will automatic call the other function due to the name logger that can be used by calling `logger = Logger()` - However I want that both Logger() and Script() should exchange values by each other. By that I wrote a script etc how I mean:

Logger:

```
Logger class here:
    import sys


    class Logger:

        def log(self, text):
            sys.stdout.write("{}".format(text))
            sys.stdout.write("\n")
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

---

```
Script class here:

    from utils import Logger


    logger = Logger()  # Logger from Utils


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            Name = 'Stackoverflow'
            logger.log(Name)


        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\n" + 'Keyboard - Interrupted)
            sys.exit()
```

---

Output would be `Stackoverflow` simple as that.

However I want to upgrade it by sending the value Stackoverflow back to Logger class.

What I want to do is that etc.

```
def log(self, text):
    sys.stdout.write("{} {}".format('[Profile-' + Name']', text))
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Where the output in that case would be:

`[Profile-Stackoverflow] New text here`

Now my question is that how can I make so Logger class would be able to take the value `Name` and add it as a `[Profile-Stackoverflow]` in that case?

Comment: I saw that I got a -1 as a vote. It would be appreciated to get a comment about it so I know what I can improve my text in the future and also edit it as it is from now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger("StackOverflow")
logger.info("HELLO!")
```

i dont understand what you are asking

**util.py**

```
import sys


class Logger:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def log(self, text):
        sys.stdout.write("[{}] - {}".format(self.name,text))
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

**other.py**

```
from util import Logger
log = Logger("Stackoverflow")
log.log("Hello")
```

Comment: I assume this is a sort of another logging than what I have? Because I created my own logger as practice so I wanted to continue with that out from the post I have above if that is possible of course :D

Comment: this is the builtin logging module ... it comes with python, and it does exactly what you are trying to do ... why would you not want to use a well vetted tool that already exists

Comment: Oh yeah. but it was just more of a practice that I want to learn how to send values between each others classes

Comment: Oh that was exactly the one I was looking for! :) Thanks!